# Multiple flashes with different trigger voltages

Tags: flash

I have the following:

- Nikon D3100 (max 250V trigger voltage)
- Vivitar 2600 flash ([148V trigger voltage](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html)*)
- Yongnuo YN465 flash (6V trigger voltage)
- [Hot shoe universal translators](http://mpex.com/2x-hot-shoe-universal-translator-kit-w-16ft-mini-mini-cable.html)**

I'd like to use both flashes wired up through the hot shoe translators. I know that my camera tolerates the trigger voltage of the 2600 on its own, but I'm not sure about the YN465 if everything is wired together.

My concern is that the translators may connect all the positive terminals together and all the negative terminals together, so that the circuit gets closed solely by the camera on trigger. This would mean that the YN465 will receive the 2600's 148V on its positive terminal (while it's producing 6V), and then when the flash triggers, the YN465 will receive 148V on its negative terminal too, when the circuit closes.

I know the camera can handle that, but I'm not sure the YN465 will be okay.

So my question is: **Should I be worried about this?** As I see it, there are some possibilities/options:

1. The YN465 can tolerate the extra voltage.
2. The YN465 can't tolerate the extra voltage, but the translators detect and relay trigger signals (and can tolerate 148V on a node). I can't imagine they do this given their price and number of connections, and they would probably need an internal power source for their internal relays/switch circuitry.
3. The translators just hardwire everything together, making it an unsafe setup if the YN465 can't tolerate 148V. A [Safe-Sync adapter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/245292-REG/Wein_W990560_Safe_Sync_Hot_Shoe_to.html) on the 2600 should work here.
4. Use a wireless or optical trigger for one of the flashes, thus removing any direct electrical connections.

My instinct tells me that 3 & 4 are the only safe options.

---

* I measured my own 2600 at about 38V, but I'll play it safe and assume the higher voltage is possible.

** Or something similar; I don't actually have these yet, otherwise I would be able to do some measurements on my own.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use  a Sync-Safe or equivalent. And I'd be much more worried about my camera than the flashes. Modern cameras are computers and designed for 5V max. Old cameras, like my Nikon F, can tolerate much higher voltages (say 300 V) at low current values.

You could also use optical sync, which eliminates the issues of voltages.

The Cactus V triggers claim to be safe for old high voltage flashes, and they are inexpensive, about $30 per unit.

Comment: Thanks for the product recommendation. The D3100 manual specifies 250V as a maximum safe trigger voltage, so my concern about the other flash was that it could end up also receiving the high voltage from the old flash, and not be as forgiving. I think I will probably go with the optical trigger for simplicity anyway.