# Would a Vivitar 2800 flash work on a Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon, flash, nikon-d3100, vivitar

Recently I've got this flash, and after researching about it and Nikon's hotshoe voltage, one doubt has appeared. In the manual of several cameras, it's written that the maximum voltage of the hotshoe is 250v, is that correct? And does it apply to my DSLR?

Info: Vivitar 2800 voltage sits between 140/170 I guess.

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html) the Vivitar 2800 has a very high variance in the trigger voltage. Users report 140-170V, but also 4, 20 and 33V. So it's probably best to measure the voltage yourself. [This previous question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34507/multiple-flashes-with-different-trigger-voltages) also mentions that the trigger voltage of the Nikon D3100 is 250V.

Comment: I measured myself, and mine gave me about 34V when idle, but I don't have a clue of when triggered. So... No risks of getting the camera fried?

Comment: To me, a novice in electronics, it sounds that if your camera can take 250V and the flash only has a trigger voltage of 170V it should be fine. Am I responsible for any damage caused this experiment? Nope.

Comment: From my basic knowledge in electronics it doesn't appear to have any problem too.  Well, thanks for the opinion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the D3100 user manual, page 172](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D3100_ENnoprint.pdf#page=188):

> ... Negative voltages or voltages over 250 V applied to the accessory shoe could not only prevent operation, but damage the sync circuitry of the camera or flash.

Given that this is the published information in the user manual, I'd say, that yes, the 250V limit applies to your camera, and as long as you know the measured sync voltage is within 0-250V, it should be safe.